# Builder Pattern vs Java Beans thread-safe

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Based on this example
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/VNA04-J.+Ensure+that+calls+to+chained+methods+are+atomic

What if I change the usage in the first example to a thread safe version
http://codeshare.io/ZYlut

Isn't it the same as the builder from the thread-safe point of view?

Comment: Your first example is not thread safe.

Comment: or if you would post MVCE ?

Comment: @sunrise76 - the first example on  https://www.securecoding.cert.org is not thread safe, my example and the builder are thread safe. Don't you agree?

Comment: Sorry. Your second example is not thread safe. First one is thread safe but we do not know final value of Currency due to getting new instance from build

Comment: Post the code in the question itself.

Comment: There is quite a bit of code there...

Comment: What he meant was: Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.